# .htaccess - 301 redirection of the set of dynamicaly generated links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Long time ago I had some links generated dynamicly. I would like to know how to do 301 redirect to all of these links matching criteria below:

> testfile.php?post=XXX

**UPDATE**

So I managed to rewrite it with code below, problem is that I still need to assign that redirection to testfile.php only.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.testdomain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Could you help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not RedirectMatch querystrings. You need to use mod-rewrite to redirect **/testfile.php?post=foobar** to the homepage of **testdomain.com** .

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /testfile\.php?post=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://testdomain.com/? [L,R]
```

Edit : not sure why the above working rule failed on your server.

If you want the rule to apply only to **testfile.php** , change your regex pattern to **^testfile.php$** :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^testfile\.php$ http://www.testdomain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: could you taka a look, there is progress, but sitll not what i want exactly